# How to read and update(increment) a value in a file with shell commands

Tags: linux, file, shell

I have a certain file which contains many contents, including a line from the format (for example)

ABC = "x12"

What I need to do is to increment the value, so that after the command it will be

ABC = "x13"

The file itself needs to be updated, no need to create a new file or something similar.

I would appreciate if someone do this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my quick-and-dirty solution using `sed`:

```
sed -i 's|\([a-zA-Z]* \= \)\"\([A-Za-z]\+\)\([0-9)]\+\)\(\"\)| echo \1 \\"\2$(expr \3 + 1 )\\" |ge' ~/file.txt
```

Example:

```
$ cat ~/file.txt
ABC = "x12"
$ sed -i 's|\([a-zA-Z]* \= \)\"\([A-Za-z]\+\)\([0-9)]\+\)\(\"\)| echo \1 \\"\2$(expr \3 + 1 )\\" |ge' ~/file.txt
$ cat ~/file.txt
ABC = "x13"
$ # works for other keys as well:
$ cat ~/file2.txt
KEY = "y12"
$ sed -i 's|\([a-zA-Z]* \= \)\"\([A-Za-z]\+\)\([0-9)]\+\)\(\"\)| echo \1 \\"\2$(expr \3 + 1 )\\" |ge' ~/file2.txt
$ cat ~/file2.txt
KEY = "y13"
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Manuel, this worked great. The only problem that I have now is that it also changes other similar instances in the file... My request wasn't specific enough and you provided a general solution which works great. I'll have to slightly modify it to change only my file.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using perl one-liner:

```
perl -e '$abc=x12;for(1..2){print $abc++," ";}'
```